# Multiple update with one post request

Tags: spring-boot, rest

```
    public User save(User user) #function for add user in list
{
    users.add(user);
    return user;
}
```

## mapping for post request

```
@PostMapping("/users") 
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        User savdUser= service.save(user);

        URI location=ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(savdUser.getId()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

}

## but give suggestion for this multiple data at one post request

```
[{
"id":7,
"name":"aptech",
"birthDate":"2020-05-08T10:09:07.799+00:00"

},
{
"id":7,
"name":"aptech",
"birthDate":"2020-05-08T10:09:07.799+00:00"

}]
```

## this is the error, suggest me java function take multiple users from post requesr

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-09T07:06:46.212+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
```

Comment: The request contains a list of users while the code only handles a single user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create method for getting List of User  as a resource
it can be something like this

```
@PostMapping("/users/bulk") 
    public List<User> createUser(@RequestBody List<User> users)
    {
        for(User user : users){
          User savdUser= service.save(user);
          URI location=ServletUriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("localhost").port(8080).path("/users/{id}").buildAndExpand(savdUser.getId()).toUri();
          List<User> savedUsers;
          savedUsers.add((User) ResponseEntity.created(location).build().getBody();
        }

        return savedUsers;
    }
```